# Aurelia: Lazy load of js+html features with FrameworkConfiguration?

Tags: aurelia

I want to configure a lazy load of some features with both js and html elements.
 If I do `aurelia.use.feature('js+html-custom-element')` in `configure()` of `main.ts`  everything works as expected.
 But when I postpone loading like

```
 return new FrameworkConfiguration(aurelia)            
            .feature('js+html-custom-element')
            .apply();
```

then browser loads both js and html files but html is not rendered!? No errors in a console window.

In case with `'js-only-custom-element'` lazy load works as expected.

Is this expected behaviour, bug or am I missing something?

`aurelia-framework` 1.1.5 `jspm` +`type script` solution.

Comment: `.feature('folder')` is to be used to load `folder/index.js` which should implement a `configure(config) {}` function. Is it what you were doing?

Comment: In `index.ts` of `'folder'` I have `export function configure(aurelia) { aurelia.globalResources( './js+html-custom-element');}`

Answer (score 0):

Aurelia uses strong file naming convention.
For component, if the file defines `class JsHtmlCustomElement`, Aurelia expects the file name is `js-html-custom-element.js`.

For value converter (or binding behaviour, custom attribute), it can

1. either use naming convention `foo-bar.js` for `class
   FooBarValueConverter`.
2. or with help of annotation `foo-bar.js` for
   `@valueConverter('fooBar') export class FooBar`.

Comment: Files are `btn-export.ts` and `btn-export.html`. In `.ts` file there is `@customElement('btn-export')
@autoinject
export class BtnExport {...}` It seems that naming convention is ok.

Comment: In your original question, you mentioned `.feature('js+html-custom-element')` in `main.ts`, and also `aurelia.globalResources( './js+html-custom-element');` in `js+html-custom-element/index.ts` file. It looked to me you were trying to load `js+html-custom-element/js+html-custom-element.ts` component.